# The way of the Swan

Tags: shiva, mantras

Where we can find the well known **sō’ham** specifically referred to Siva?

Which Tantra/Slokas or any related text repeat this celebrated mantra as a form of worship to Mahadev?

Comment: soham is hamsa but hamsa is referred as Lakshmi Narayana not shiva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (कुलार्णवतन्त्रम्)- देहो देवालयो देवि जीवो देवः सदाशिवः ।
> त्यजेदज्ञाननिर्माल्य सोऽहम्भावेन पूजयेत् ॥

Meaning: Lord shiva says 'O devi Parvati' This body (देह) is itself the Devālay (देवालय)! It consists of a God called 'jivā' (जीव). Shstra(शास्त्र) calls this (सदाशिव) sadāshivā! It has been covered with lack of knowledge, the followers responsiblity is to remove this cover & worship it with 'sóhām bhāvā' through the medium of 'Ajapa-japa'.

Although not mantra, the 'sóhām' is associated with shiva here.
'Ajapa-japa' is the practice of japa without the mental effort normally needed to repeat the mantra.

Comment: and what is your source for saying this?

Comment: 9th ullasa, 41th verse